# How to get rid of circle stroke in firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In firemonkey, when adding a circle it comes with a black border. I want to get rid of this border.

When adding a `TCircle` to fmx and changing its color it looks like the picture below.

[image: circle with black border]

I want it without the border, like the one below.

[image: circle without black border]

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below

1. Select the `TCircle`
2. Go to its Fill property in the Object Inspector
3. Click in the three dots in front of (Brush)
4. A pop up comes up, in the top menu select border, then select none.

To illustrate.

[image: click here to change stroke]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Stroke` not `Fill`?

Comment: When you click in Fill, it will pop up a window with stroke. That was why I delayed to find it.